# Django on Twisted with multiple virtual hosts?

Tags: django, twisted

I have a django website that I am hosting on twisted via the django WSGIHandler as described here - http://www.clemesha.org/blog/Django-on-Twisted-using-latest-twisted-web-wsgi

All seems OK up to the point where I want to add an extra "site" configuration to my django site using the django Sites framework. Doing so, I add an extra settings.py file for the new site and that seems to work.

What I then want to do is use the twisted NameVirtualHost class to be able to direct one domain (say site1.example.com) to the first settings file, then use another domain (say site2.example.com) to use the second settings file. This works with Apache & mod_wsgi.

The problem I face is that the twisted code can only access one django environment at a time. If I call setup_environ with the first settings file and setup a host for the first domain, a subsequent call to setup_environ will replace the settings file in use so therefore only one set of settings can be used at one time.

Any ideas how to proceed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gave up on this in the end. Looks like you cannot easily access 2 Django environments within the same twisted instance. I think it would require multiple instances of twisted with a reverse proxy or some sort of multiprocess hacking - either way its not worth the effort for me so I'm going to try something else...